# Comparative with verbs

Tags: verb, comparison

How do you compare verbs?

> Netflix is better than buying DVDs or going to the cinema.

Would I use *zu* with the verbs, or convert them to nouns?

> Netflix ist besser als DVDs zu kaufen oder ins Kino zu gehen.
>
> Netflix ist besser als DVD-kaufen oder Kino-gehen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct translation would be

> Netflix ist besser als DVDs zu kaufen oder ins Kino zu gehen.

While in English you use a gerund when comparing things, in German you use the preposition "zu" with the verb, literally translated as

> Netflix is better than to buy DVDs or to go to the cinema.

In informal use, you could even leave out the "zu", as Lupino suggested, but the grammatically correct and most commonly used way is to keep the preposition.

You could theoretically also convert them to nouns and as such use a gerund, by saying

> Netflix ist besser als das Kaufen (/der Kauf) von DVDs oder der Gang ins Kino.

, but this has a formal sound and is uncommon.

Comment: I feel a certain unease regarding the comparison of a noun with a verb in the first translation.

Answer (score 3):

According to my linguistic competence of German it is completely okay to translate it straight forward:

> Netflix ist besser als DVDs kaufen oder ins Kino gehen

Comment: Your translation is informal and fine for a conversation. If you want to write it though, you should use "Netflix ist besser als DVDs zu kaufen oder ins Kino zu gehen". This is the grammatically correct way to say it and the most commonly used.

Comment: While not 100% correct this wording adds a somewhat laid-back touch. Yo man!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the given sentence is slightly different.

> Skype ist besser als Leute zu treffen oder anzurufen.

Then it would be natural, altough perhaps not necessary, to convert both things you are comparing to the same kind of grammatical object, i.e. to verbalize the left hand side or to nominalize the right hand side:

1. **Verbalization.**

   > Skypen ist besser als Leute zu treffen oder anzurufen.
   >   *oder*
   >   Skype zu nutyen ist besser als Leute zu treffen oder anzurufen.
2. **Nominalization.**

   > Skype ist besser als ein echtes Treffen oder als ein gewönlicher Anruf.

The given example from informal to formal.

> 1. Netflix ist besser als DVDs oder Kino.
> 2. Netfilx ist besser als DVDs kaufen oder ins Kino gehen.*
> 3. Netfilx ist besser als DVDs zu kaufen oder ins Kino zu gehen.*
> 4. Sich bei Netflix anzumelden ist besser als DVDs zu Kaufen oder ins Kino zu gehen.
> 5. ({Ein Vertrag mit · *oder*  · Die Anmeldung bei}) Netflix ist besser als der Kauf von DVDs oder der Gang ins Kino. (Klingt vielleicht künstlich, zumiendest für dieses Thema)

*Here, as pointed out in the comments below other answers, **2** and **3** might motivate little objections. The former drops the *zu*; but if it's restored, then **2** is converted into **3**, which now compares a noun with two verbs. But I doubt somebody wouldn't understand them and they seem to be completely common. To get out of trouble, I'd use **1**, though. If my interlocutor knows what Netflix is, then (s)he doesn't need the verbs in **2** and **3**.  That option, however, wouldn't answer your question.

So *your* first attempt is right, the second is wrong.

(Aber eigentlich finde ich Netflix *nicht* besser als Kino. Nie.)